# Simulation keyboard events in minecraft with an auto-keyboard

Tags: c#, automation, minecraft

So I'm playing minecraft and I want to make a program that switches the tool on a set time frame, meaning it switches to the second item slot in the toolbar and then the third and so on. If you're curious I'm playing skyblock and have a cobblestone generator. It works perfectly in notepad and other "textboxes" like chrome with the timing and everything but it seems that minecraft does not allow simulated keyboard presses because it does not respond to the input given by the program. Even if i have the game in full screen (f11) it does not seem to work. Do you think the program itself is faulty or do I need to adapt it for minecraft specifically? Any tips at all would be very appreciated.

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;

    timer1.Start();
    if (textBox1.Text == "")
    {
        int interval = 1; // set to 1 second for testing purposes. This is 200 in practise. 
        timer1.Interval = interval * 1000;
    }
    else
    {
        int interval = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        timer1.Interval = 1000 * interval;
    }
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (i > 9)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    i++;
    keyboardPress(i);
} 

private void keyboardPress(int i)
{
    SendKeys.Send(Convert.ToString(i));
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that it works in the minecraft chat box, meaning that the input is being sent to the game but something is preventing it to act like a player interaction.

Comment: Java Edition or Bedrock Edition?